# Coin Piker Script

Tags: c#

hey i making my first game and I have a problem with coin piker script
can somebody tell mi why my script won't work on unity?
my script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CoinPicker : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public float coin = 0;

     private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
     {
         if (other.transform.tag == "Coins")
         {
             Destroy(other.gameObject);
         }
     }
     
 }
```

Comment: Walk us through the code, line by line, telling us what each line does and how it helps meet the goal you're trying to achieve

Comment: first public float coin actually  doing nothing yet because it will do something when I add a coin counter script later 

private void and if other.transform would make that if the player have got a collision with coin collider , coin will deapear

Comment: In what way is it not working? How are you expecting it to behave? How does it behave differently from what you are expecting? If it's throwing an exception, please add the exception details and stack trace to your question.